# If we can find the selected value belongs to a certain Category in HTML Select tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-select, optgroup

I am really scratching my head to find if there is any way to find the selected group of the selected option in the HTML Select Tag.

I thought of getting parent of the selected value but could not get the right solution. but we cannot rule out this option as well.

```
<select id="selectName">
    <option value="0">-- Select --</option>
    <optgroup label="Section -- 1">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Section -- 2">
        <option value="100">Hundred</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

I rally do not want to write my code like this...

```
$val = $('#selectName').val()

if($val >=1 && $val <= 4){/* ... */}
else if(/*-- another range --*/){/* ... */}
```

I wonder if there is a way we can find the group name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

```
var optgroup = $("#selectName :selected").parent("optgroup");
if (optgroup.length) {
    var label = optgroup.attr("label");
    if (label == " ... ") {
        // do something
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/3Sqjh/

Comment: Yes, this is right. I can get the Parent like this. But i cannot play with the lable. Lable might not be same all the time. Thinking of i18n. But attr() gave me another idea, I can use my own tag to differentiate.

Comment: I added another attribute that would solve my problem. Thanks. http://jsfiddle.net/3Sqjh/2/

Answer (score 1):

Do you want like this?

```
$("#selectName").change(function(){
    $val = $('#selectName :selected').parent().attr('label');
    alert($val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Creates an alert with the label-text of the parent group of selected element:

```
var $group = $('#selectName option:selected').parent();
alert($group.attr("label"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').change(function(e){
  var group = $('select option:selected').parent('optgroup');
  var groupText = group.attr('label');
});
```

[Demo on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/opehag/edit)